# How to prove Exercise 1.x.11 in Brenner & Scott's FEM book?

Tags: real-analysis, finite-element-method

I don't know how to prove Exercise 1.x.11 on Page 43 of Brenner & Scott's book "The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods", even though a hint is provided in the book. Could you please provide some help? Many thanks!

The original exercise is as below.

**Exercise** 1.x.11 Show that the condition in Example 1.2.6 implies that

$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} r^{n-1} |\rho(r)| = 0.
$$

**Example** 1.2.6 Let $\rho$ be a smooth function defined for $0 < r \leq 1$ satisfying

$$
\int_0^1 |\rho'(r)|r^{n-1} \; {\rm d} r < \infty.
$$